# Invalid cast from System.Double to System.Nullable

Tags: dapper

I have a column in my database that is a float. My database is in brazilian portuguese, so, the decimal separator from this column is comma (,).

I don't know if this is the cause, but Dapper is throwing the exception "Invalid cast from 'System.Double' to 'System.Nullable..." (my entity uses a Nullable for this column).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with culture - the data that comes back is primitive, not stringified. Simply, it isn't happy to cast from `double` to `decimal?`. Since the database is returning `double`, a `double?` property would work fine. The core *tries* to allow as many conversions as are pragmatic, but it doesn't support *all* mappings.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with Dapper using a nullable column with a non-nullable value type. @MarcGravell is right, just use the ? syntax on your value type and it should work.

Comment: @Adam the problem is the difference between double and decimal, not nullable vs non-nullable